# Hosting a match on MGO3

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-online

One of the big complaints going around at the moment about Metal Gear Online 3 is the Host disconnect issue in Automatches, which leads to experience points being lost.

So my question is whether there is any way to choose to be a host in an Automatch, or is it just completely random? As I understand it currently, creating a match isn't the same format as an Automatch where there is an infinite loop of matches.

Comment: Probably not, each game needs a host and typically it is the one with the best connection to all other players. In COD games I known I've seen "host migration" when the host leaves, it's possible that MGO just doesn't have that feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hosts are assigned automatically when a game is created, you cannot choose to be a host.

[As of patch 1.02](http://www.konami.jp/mgs_portal/jp/info/index.php?d=201512&id=771), host migration has been implemented:

```
【Host Migration】
・A new host will be selected when a host abandons the match, allowing all other players in that match to restart the match with a new host. (PlayStation®3/PlayStation®4/XboxONE)
　* This new option will allow players to join a match and stay on the same team as their party members, because the team split will not occur until enough players join the match.
・All experience points gained through the abandoned match will be given to all players in that match except the host.
```